# How to generate a string using the ISO-8859-15 charset in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, character-encoding, utf

In Java I am able to generate strings that use the ISO-8859-15 charset (sometimes referred to as Latin-9) using the following code:

```
byte[] chars = {(byte) 0x23, (byte) 0x20,...};
Charset charset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-15");
String s = new String(chars, charset);
```

How can I generate the same strings in JavaScript?

In other words, I know the value of each of the characters of the string in ISO/IEC 8859-15, I just don't know how to create a string from these values, specifying the charset.

This is for system that has Java and JavaScript components, and the generated strings must be 100% compatible.

Answer (score 1):

The best i can come up with:

```
const buf = Buffer.from([0x23, 0x20]);
console.log(buf.toString('latin1'));
```